# RxJava and-then-when

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to use RxJava in combination with Retrofit in my Android app.

I came to a point where I need to retrieve (GET) a url from some model class, and if its not available, POST to another endpoint to generate it, then retrieve it with GET again.

The idea is that the end result is always a url (provided there was not an error, of course), so if its not there, we create it and then retrieve it.

I can do this with RxJava by just nesting calls, but this does not seem to "reactive", so I thought maybe the and-when-then sounds like what im looking for? I tried looking for examples but these three words are quite difficult to search due to them being so common.

Is it possible to combine observables to achieve what I describe?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have the following methods:

```
apiManager.makeGETRequest();  //returns Url or throws an Exception
apiManager.makePOSTRequest(); //returns Url
```

Use handy `onErrorResumeNext` operator:

```
apiManager.makeGETRequest()
    .onErrorResumeNext(t -> apiManager.makePOSTRequest())
    ...
```

It intercepts an `Exception` and replaces it with `Observable`. In your case if `makeGETRequest()` succeeds, than downstream will ignore `onErrorResumeNext`, otherwise `apiManager.makePOSTRequest()` will be called.

P.S. Don't forget to check what kind of exception you receive in `onErrorResumeNext`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful for you.

https://github.com/darylteo/rxjava-promises/tree/master/rxjava-promises

If you need code sample for retrofit + rx usage you can follow this link.

http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/